# how to escape string and do some (if) logic in javascript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a code like this :

```
if (tmp_loket==0) {
    for (var i = 1; i<= data['jumlah_loket']; i++) {
        loket = '<div class="col-md-3" style="width: 32%;">'+
            '<div class="'+ i +
                    ' jumbotron" style="padding: 0px;">'+
                '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="width: 100%;">'+ if(i==1){ 'UMUM' } +'</button>'+
                '<h1> '+data["init_counter"][i]+' </h1>'+
                '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card">&nbsp;</span>LOKET '+ i +'</button>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>';
        $(".loket").append(loket);
    }

    tmp_loket = data['jumlah_loket'];
}
```

I want when looping is executed, value `i = 1` then what appears is `"UMUM"`, when value `i = 2` then what appears is `"ANAK"`.

But how to escape this single quote and do (if) logic?

here is the problem :

```
'<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="width: 100%;">'+ if(i==1){ 'UMUM' } +'</button>'+
```

Thank you.

Comment: if you have more than just two strings, you can create an array of strings, then retrieve your desired string using `i-1`. No need for an if-statement

Comment: yup, it really didn't occur to me . thankyou bro

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary [`?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Conditional_(ternary)_operator) operator instead:

```
..... + (i === 1 ? 'UMUM' : 'ANAK') + .....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and, as Nick Parsons says, an array in stead of an if statement:

```js
const words = ['UMUM', 'ANAK'];
let tmp_loket = 0;
let data = {jumlah_loket:2, init_counter:[4,5,6,7,8]};

if (tmp_loket==0) {
                for (var i = 1; i<= data['jumlah_loket']; i++) {
                    loket = `<div class="col-md-3" style="width: 32%;">
                                <div class="${i} jumbotron" style="padding: 0px;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="width: 100%;">${words[i-1]}</button>
                                    <h1> ${data["init_counter"][i]} </h1>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="width: 100%;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card">&nbsp;</span>LOKET ${i}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>`;
                    $(".loket").append(loket);
                }

                tmp_loket = data['jumlah_loket'];
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loket"></div>
```

Comment: whoa thank you very much bro, why don't I think of using arrays :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
var string = '<button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" style="width: 100%;">';
if(i == 1){
 var string = string + 'UMUM</button>';
}
else if(i == 2){
 var string = string + 'ANAK</button>';
}
```